# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Not Finding Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to set up a basic Android App that will have Bluetooth LE functionality as per the documentation on the Android Developers site.  I successfully can get to the point where I am starting a scan, but it is not finding any of the peripherals I have been using to test. Here is the code as it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Bind(R.id.button) Button mButton;
@Bind(R.id.listView) ListView mListView;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning = true;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothAdapterBluetoothLeScanner;
ArrayList<String> bluetoothArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Context mContext = getBaseContext();
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapterBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1900);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    scanLeDevice(mScanning);
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
//            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//                @Override
//                public void run() {
//                    mScanning = false;
//                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
//                }
//            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                 byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("test" ,device.getName());

                    }
                });
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know exactly what the advertising data content is? Maybe it's blocked by the bluetooth stack(bluetooth.default.so) .For example, if the advertising device has not set the "discoverable bit" in AD flag, it will be blocked and you will not receive the report in your callback function.